# What is the best approach to using createjs.LoadQueue across multiple classes?

Tags: createjs

This is a question about code structure/pattern. Here is my code setup:

- I have a `Game` class that loads all resources (images, sounds, fonts, etc.) for a game using a `LoadQueue` object.
- I have a `Hero` class which inherits from the `createjs.Sprite` class. When `Game` instantiates `Hero`, it passes it the sprite to use as a parameter.
- The `Hero` fires bullets. These are created from the `Bullet` class which inherits from the `createjs.Bitmap` class.

How should I pass down (or otherwise retrieve) the image needed by the `Bullet` class?

Show I create a static/global instance of the `LoadQueue` which is available everywhere? Should I pass the bullet image to the `Hero` who in turn passes it to the `Bullet`? Should I pass the `LoadQueue` instance down the stream? Should I use separate `LoadQueue` objects?

How do you handle multiple classes (using ES6's module approach) needing resources loaded by a single `LoadQueue`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of how you want to architect things. A few options:

1) Pass either loaded images around. If your app gets big it means passing a bunch of images to views as well, which is not ideal.

```
let view = new View({heroImage, bmpImage}); // In the main view
let hero = new HeroSprite(images.heroImage); // Inside the constructor
```

2) Create a singleton-style reference to your queue

```
let queue = SingletonClassReference.queue;
let hero = new HeroSprite(queue.getResult("hero"));
```

3) Use an asset manager.

```
init() {
    this.assets = new AssetManager();
}
handleComplete(event) {
    // When an asset loads
    this.assets.register(event.item.id, item.item.result); // API TBD
}
// Somewhere
let assets = getReferenceToAssets(); // Either pass it around or make it singleton
let hero = assets.get("hero");
```

**This is all just pseudo-code.**

Passing references around is messy, and couples your code really tightly, so it is not ideal. Making some sort of static assets class or queue instance is much more modular, but implementation really depends on your preferences. I am not suggesting any of these as best practices – just some quick ideas on how to work with the assets.

Adobe Animate solved this for CreateJS animations using a global `images` object that preloaded assets got dumped onto, which was a little messy but worked. In more recent releases, they implemented a lookup for animations, which has an `images` object on it for easy access.

Cheers,

Comment: Passing stuff around really is something I tried and it really is a pain that I would like to avoid. Since I'm using ES6 modules I wouldn't go with option 2 either but I guess I could create a singleton AssetManager that gets imported by classes that need loaded resources. I'll have to give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pointers from Lanny, what I ended up doing is creating a `Loader` module which simply exports a single instance of `createjs.LoadQueue`:

```
export default new createjs.LoadQueue();
```

Then, when I want to use it in another module, I simply import it like so:

```js
import Loader from "./Loader.js";

export default class Demo {

  loadResources() {
      Loader.addEventListener('complete', this.start.bind(this));
      Loader.loadManifest("manifest.json");
  }

  start() {
    let test = new createjs.Bitmap(Loader.getResult("test"));
  }

}
```

Since modules are only evaluated once, this makes the `Loader` a singleton which is exactly what I wanted. However, this seems too easy. Am I missing something obvious or is this a sound approach?